# How to rsync/fetch/download the folder open with ssh/tramp

Tags: dired, files, remote

I work in a folder on the server, peyote2 in this case. I can edit files there etc, we all know that. However I have there a pdb file (RNA 3D structure) that to view I have to download it to my computer.

What would be the easiest way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `dired-dwim-target` is set to `t`, split the frame in two windows, open a local directory in the other window with dired where you want the copy to land,  mark the file that you want to copy with `C` on the remote directory, check that the destination is correctly set to the local directory and press `RET`.

Comment: That was quick! Even easier than I though! Copy also folders! Thanks.